# What is "確かにコレじゃあな" supposed to mean here?

Tags: translation, meaning, syntax

The scenario:
Two people looking at a picture of their deceased relative.

Person 1:

> はぁーあ、こんな遺影じゃおちおち感傷にも浸れない

Which I believe translates to:

> I shouldn't get sentimental so carelessly over something like a picture

Person 2:

> 確かにコレじゃあなー

This response is confusing me, if 確かに means "certainly", コレ means "this" and  じゃあなー means "isn't it/right?" then that would would mean it literally translates to "certainly this isn't it", I know I shouldn't think of things too literally but I'm at a loss as to what it could mean in a more contextual sense, can anyone please explain what it actually means?

Answer (score 3):

You have mixed up じゃねえ and じゃあなー. In speech ない contracts to ねえ/ねぇ/ねー, but never to なあ/なぁ/なー (except in Nagoya dialect where ない sounds similar to なぁ /næː/).

- 確かに: "certainly"
- コレ: "this"
- じゃあ: (colloquialism for では)

  - で: "with/by" (method/means marker)
  - は: (topic/contrast marker, here used to [indicate some negative expression follows](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010))
- なー: ([sentence-end/filler particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5240/5010) like ねー)

So this literally translates to "Certainly, with this, <*something negative left unsaid*>." A possible translation would be "With this...yeah." or even "You can say that."

By the way こんな遺影 is "a portrait (of deceased person) like this", not "something like a portrait". And why is [おちおち](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1) translated as carelessly?

Answer (score 3):

The conversation suggests there is something amiss about that particular photo, which makes it difficult for them to indulge in sentimentalism as they like.

Person 1 goes like this:

> Man, with his/her portrait like this, it's impossible to get properly sentimental.

Person 2 agrees:

> Yeah, not with (the portrait like) this.

Notice that the じゃあ is the same thing as the じゃ in Person 1's line.  It's the colloquial contraction of the compound particle では, made up of で(*with*) + は(topic marker).

Answer (score 0):

Its picture was so terrible.

> That's right.  (This picture is too bad to get sentimental.  Although I dare not to say, but you are aware of my opinion, aren't you?)